# Balanced Search Tree Query, Asymtotic Analysis

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

The situation is as follows:-

> We have n number and we have print
>   them in sorted order. We have access
>   to balanced dictionary data structure,
>   which supports the operations serach,
>   insert, delete, minimum, maximum each
>   in O(log n) time.
>
> We want to retrieve the numbers in
>   sorted order in O(n log n) time using
>   only the insert and in-order
>   traversal.

The answer to this is:-

```
Sort()
  initialize(t)
  while(not EOF)
     read(x)
     insert(x,t);
  Traverse(t);
```

Now the query is if we read the elements in time "n" and then traverse the elements in "log n"(in-order traversal) time,, then the total time for this algorithm (n+logn)time, according to me.. Please explain the follow up of this algorithm for the time calculation.. How it will sort the list in O(nlogn) time??

Thanks.

Comment: If this is homework please tag as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each insert is `O(log n)`. You are doing `n` inserts, so that gives `n * O(log n) = O(n log n)` asymptotic time complexity. Traversing the tree is `O(n)`, because there are `n` nodes. That adds up to `O(n + n log n)` which differs from `O(n log n)` by a constant, so the final asymptotic complexity is `O(n log n)`..

> and then traverse the elements in "log n

Traversal is `O(n)`, not `O(log n)`. An insertion is `O(log n)`, and you're doing `n` such insertions.

Comment: Yes, this is essentially a heapsort that the OP is describing which is O(n log n).